# How to create Google map with multiple addresses dynamically?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am working on a real-estate website, I have made a PHP CMS for this site. I want to add one function, which works as follows.

- I have a section named "Properties" in this website.
- In this section, Client can add the property details like address, Image, specialty cost etc, via CMS.
- When we add the address via CMS, I want that address to be shown on the google map shown beside.

How is it possible?

Comment: Please post your code in question, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is using [Google Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). You can ask the admin to enter multiple fields while adding a property. For example:

`Property Name, Property Address, Property Locality (Google Place Autocomplete), Pincode, City, State, Country`.

With Google Place Autocomplete you can easily get [the lat/lng, pincode, city, state, country](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) of the location entered.

There is one more work around but not recommended. In one of my old project I didn't have latitude and longitude of the properties/places. So what I did was simple google map search. If that place has been tagged on google map already you `might` get proper location on map. You can try embedding the following url.

`https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_KEY&q=PROPERTY_NAME,PROPERTY_LOCATION`